# change classes and hover behaviour

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class='m1 backblue'>323</div>
<div class='m2wrap'>
<div class='m2 backblue'>525</div>
<div class='m2 backblue'>727</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.backblue{
    background:#0099CC;
}
.backblue:hover{
    background:#00bfff;
}
.backgreen{
    background:#2e8b57;
}
.backgreen:hover{
    background:#33cc33;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#pointgreen').click(function(){
    $('.m1, .m2').removeClass('backblue').addClass('backgreen');
});
```

After clicking on `#pointgreen` everything works except `.backgreen:hover` on `.m2`. Hovering this class doesn't change background color.

Comment: where is the pointgreen?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Everything seems to work fine with the code you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/gdv7wg5o/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, `#pointgreen` is a separate div, something like a button.

Comment: @Esko, thanks, I checked everything again, doesn't work on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly here on your code:
[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nna3nscw/1/)
I've changed `.click` to `.on('click',` method.

You should inspect element and see in styles what else overrides your :hover color

Comment: You're right. Another function overrides the current changes. Thanks.